# Drag bar on side to resize element width independently, any number of elements on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I'm trying to independently resize width of element(`.box`) by their own handle.
With what i got together only the last element is resizable.
`Min-width` and `max-width` shouldn't be a issue since it's taken care of with css.

I'd like to:

1. Independently resize width of any element(`.box`) by their handle(`.handle`).
   (when its handle is dragged only that box resizes)
2. Optimize the code, example `whenDragging()` function (right now `'mouseup'` event is called even when i'm not resizing) - not sure if needed?

```js
var isHandlerDragging = false;

var handlers = document.querySelectorAll('.handler');
  for( i=0; i < handlers.length; i++ ){
    var handler = handlers[i];
};
  
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
  for( i=0; i < wrappers.length; i++ ){
    var wrapper = wrappers[i];
};

var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
  for( i=0; i < boxes.length; i++ ){
    var box = boxes[i];
};

function whenDragging() {
  if(isHandlerDragging === true){
    document.querySelector('*').style.userSelect = "none";
    document.querySelector('*').style.pointerEvents = "none";      
    document.querySelector('*').style.cursor = "ew-resize";
  }else{
    document.querySelector('*').style.cssText = null;
  };
}

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.target === handler) {
    isHandlerDragging = true;
  }
  whenDragging()
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (!isHandlerDragging) {
    return false;
  }
  var containerOffsetLeft = wrapper.offsetLeft;
  var pointerRelativeXpos = e.clientX - containerOffsetLeft;
  box.style.width = pointerRelativeXpos + 'px';
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  isHandlerDragging = false;
  whenDragging()
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  margin-top:20px;
}

.box{
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  min-width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border:0;
  background-color:black;
}

.handler{
  width:20px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <iframe class="box"></iframe>
  <div class="handler"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <iframe class="box"></iframe>
  <div class="handler"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the boxes should get resized independently (i.e. when its handle is dragged only that box resizes) or are you saying that if one box (class.box) is so dragged then they all should get resized the same? I can't tell from your snippet because quite a few statements do nothing. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: @AHaworth I meant independently, thank you for letting me know, edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of main features to note in this example:

- the wrappers are flex boxes so we have to consider what happens if we try to keep those at 100% width but alter the elements inside, given one has its width set in px terms
- the box elements are iframes. This means that by default any mouse event on them is not acted on (at this level) with the result that the user moving the cursor over them does nothing.

There are a few other things in the code that need altering - in particular what action is taken on mouse up/down/move - the code in the question uses the same box element all the time (by mistake I believe) so we change it to pick up the current box on mousedown on the handler associated with it. We also make it be the wrapper that has max width 100% (of its container) so there is no possibility of moving the cursor right to the right hand edge making the handler go out of the container.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

let box = ''; //initial situation, no box is being dragged

container.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('handler')) {
    box = e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.box');
  }
});

container.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (box != '') {
   box.parentElement.style.width = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px';
  }
});

container.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {//from mouseup
  box = '';
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.box{
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  /*max-width:100%;*/
  min-width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border:0;
  background-color:black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.handler{
  display: inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

iframe {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <iframe class="box"></iframe>
    <div class="handler"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <iframe class="box"></iframe>
    <div class="handler"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: the mouse actions on the iframes are now seen by setting pointer-events to none. This may or may not be suitable in a real-world scenario but it answers the question as set.